# What is the conditional expectation $E(X^2\mid X+Y=1) $ if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d standard normal?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

> $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d and follow standard normal distribution.
>   What is the conditional expectation $E(X^2\mid X+Y=1)$?

Also, I have seen methods of calculating conditional expectation scattered in literatures. Some use a fraction of integral of probability density functions; while others use "hacky" properties of random variables' distributions. What is a good starting point of calculating a conditional expectation?

Comment: Do you wish to assume that $X,Y$ are both $N(0,1)$ or $N(\mu,\sigma)$ ?

Comment: @N8tron Edited. Standard normal distribution.

Comment: There is no 'master formula' for computing conditional expectation in general setting. So a 'hacky' way is really helpful when it is available. Otherwise, you need to look at the joint distribution...

Comment: Since $(X,X+Y)$ is jointly normal, $X\mid X+Y$ is univariate normal, from which the expectation follows.

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid you'll find this "hacky" but...

Consider the transformed variables $S=X+Y$ , $R=X-Y$. It's easy to see that these variables (which correspond to a scaled 45 degrees rotation) are iid, $N(0,2)$.

Now $X=(S+R)/2$. Then we want

$$\begin{align}
E[X^2 \mid  S] &= E\left[\left(\frac{S+R}{2}\right)^2 \mid S\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(E[S^2\mid S] + 2 E[S R \mid S] + E[R^2\mid S] \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(S^2 + 2 S E[R ] + E[R^2] \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}(S^2+2)
\end{align}
$$

Or

$$ E[X^2 \mid  X+Y=1] = \frac{1}{4}(1^2+2)=\frac{3}{4}$$

Quick sanity check: recall that we must have $E[E[X^2 \mid S]]= E[X^2]=1$. And, indeed $E[\frac{1}{4}(S^2+2)]=\frac{1}{4}(2+2)=1$.

Comment: Could you explain how does it work here: $\frac{1}{4}\left(S^2 + 2 S E[R ] + E[R^2] \right) =\frac{1}{4}(S^2+2)$?

Comment: I've noted before that $R$ is $N(0,2)$ (normal, with zero mean and variance $=2$)

Comment: Oh, right - now I see everything. Thank you!