# conditional expectation $E[{X_1}^2+{X_2}^2|X_1+X_2=t] $ of normal distributed variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

to find the conditional expectation
$E[{X_1}^2+{X_2}^2|X_1+X_2=t] $

if $X_i$'s are independent and both are std. normal distributed.

My attempt:
as given is $X_1+X_2=t$ , take $X_2= t-X_1$ and calculate

$E[{X_1}^2+(t-X_1)^2]$

$=E[2{X_1}^2-2tX_1+t^2]=2E[{X_1}^2]-2tE[X_1]+t^2$

$=2+t^2$

this gives a multiple of correct answer $(=1+\frac{t^2}{2})$ altough I'm not sure what is wrong in this method.
Can smn point out mistakes if present?

Edit: I got a correct and easier solution other than the one mentioned so now I am just looking for a mistake in the one suggested Please.

Comment: If there is an assumption of independence here that should be mentioned.

Comment: The mistake is that $\operatorname{E}(X_1^2 + (t - X_1)^2 \mid X_1 + X_2 = t) \neq \operatorname{E}(X_1^2 + (t - X_1)^2)$.

Comment: is there a relation between the two?

Comment: Not a direct relation, since you can add an arbitrary multiple of $X_1 + X_2 - t$ to $X_1^2 + X_2^2$, making the unconditional expectation of the result take any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is to note that for $T=X_1+X_2$, both $(X_1,T)$ and $(X_2,T)$ have the same bivariate normal distribution. In fact, $$(X_1,T)\sim N_2\left[ 0, \begin{pmatrix} 1& 1/\sqrt 2 \\ 1/\sqrt 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\right ]$$

This gives the conditional distribution $$X_1\mid T\sim N\left(\frac{T}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Now use linearity of expectation to find $$E\left[X_1^2+X_2^2\mid T\right]=E\left[X_1^2\mid T\right]+E\left[X_2^2\mid T\right]$$

---

Another approach to find the conditional mean is shown in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2797541/321264) answer.

And @Maxim points out your mistake correctly.

You *cannot* simply say that $E\left[X_1^2+(t-X_1)^2\mid X_1+X_2=t\right]=E\left[X_1^2+(t-X_1)^2\right]$. This is not true because $X_1^2+(t-X_1)^2$ is not independent of $\{X_1+X_2=t\}$. When you use linearity of expectation in the next step, the condition $\{X_1+X_2=t\}$ should remain.

Comment: I don't quite understand the $X_1 \mid T \sim N(1/2, 1/2)$ notation. Do you mean $X_1 \mid (T = t) \sim N(t/2, 1/2)$?

Comment: @Maxim Yes, corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H = (X_1 + X_2 = t)$. $X_1 - X_2$ and $X_1 + X_2$ are independent as uncorrelated components of a jointly normal distribution, therefore
$$\operatorname{E}((X_1 - X_2)^2 \mid H) = \operatorname{E}((X_1 - X_2)^2), \\
2 \operatorname{E}(X_1^2 + X_2^2 \mid H) =
\operatorname{E}((X_1 + X_2)^2 \mid H) +
 \operatorname{E}((X_1 - X_2)^2 \mid H) =
t^2 + 2.$$